# Validating an object with a ManytoMany relation requirement

Tags: django, validation, many-to-many

I am struggling with a validation problem while using a manytomany relation in Django.

```
class CourseGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    color = models.Charfield(max_length=255, choices=(
        ('blue', 'Blue'), ('red', 'Red'),
        ('white', 'White')),
        helpt_text='Education level')


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    floor = models.IntegerField()
    courses = models.ManyToManyField('Course', related_name='courses')

class Teacher(models.Model):
    course_groups = models.ManyToManyField('Course', related_name='teachers')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    level = models.Charfield(max_length=1, choices=(
        ('1', 'Level 1'), (2, 'Level 2')), helpt_text='Education level')

    def validate_courses(self):
        if self.level == '1':

            groups = self.course_groups.all().prefetch_related('courses')

            color_groups = groups.filter(color__in=['red', 'blue'])
            not_has_red_or_blue = color_groups.count() < 1
            if not_has_red_or_blue:
                raise ValidationError(NotHasRedOrBlueError)

            for group in groups:
                courses = group.courses.filter(floor__eq=2)
                floor_incorrect = courses.count() < 1
                if floor_incorrect:
                    raise ValidationError(FloorNotMatchingError)

    def save(self, course_list, **kwargs):

        with transaction.atomic:
            super(Teacher, self).save()
            self.course.add(course_list)
            self.validate_courses()
```

My problem is this:

Teachers can only be saved when they are validated in relation to their CourseGroups:

1. A Teacher having level 1, should have a CourseGroup with color blue or red related. When the teacher has level 2, it doesn't matter, anything goes.
2. Next to that, when having level 1, the CourseGroup should always contain a Course that has a floor value of 2.

When saving the Teacher, it does not know which Courses are about to be related. When creating, it doesn't even have an Course.id, when it does, it doesn't know which relations will come *after* the save().

Possible solution for now: adjust the save() method, giving a list of Courses. Using transaction.atomic save the object, set the relations and validate the object with that state. If it doesn't validate, raise validation error and rollback.

Problem now remaining is the validation on the second requirement. On saving the Teacher it might validate ok on the CourseGroup because every group contains a Floor2 Course. But what to do when after saving the teacher, somewhere a Course gets removed from the CourseGroup, and the Teacher doesn't validate anymore?

Is there anyone with a better solution for this problem?